# image get distorted on uv sphere when rotating texture

Tags: texturing, uv

im facing the issue as in the photo below.
i want to rotate the y axis to animate it.
in HDRs its no issues.if i try to recreate it on a uv sphere i get this ugly distortion.
rotating the whole sphere isnt acceptable because of many reasons.
i want to rotate the texture only.

before rotate on x, y
[image]
after rotation
[image]
any solution?

Comment: Do you want to make the earth appear to be spinning on its axis by moving UV. For basic sphere mapping this can be achieved by translating  u. (longitude)

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for the help but whats u?how can i achieve that.

Comment: Go to uv editor, select all your UV map and translate it in x (keys g x)  I think thats what you.  If you select all UV's and rotate I think you will see the effect you are getting.

Comment: @batFINGER but i want ti animate the rotation of the texture(UV) anim all ad on doesnt work in recent versions i think because it doesn't affect the rotation of the UVs.

Answer (score 1):

so i have found the **answer**.

use **AnimAll add on**.

open tools panel by using T then go to Animation tab then check UVs and insert a key frame.

move to another frame then insert another key frame (by using tool menu T)

Move Uvs on any axis then insert another key frame.

go to object mode(will not work in edit mode)

switch to rendered view.

ALt+A

**your UVs will animate.**

enjoy.